# Scala cannot map list of doubles

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a case class with a property `location`, which is a tuple2 instance containing doubles.

I first convert it to a list using the following:

```
testPlace.location.productIterator.toList
```

This produces a two element list,

```
List(78.0342, -139.2234)
```

Running a simple map across this list seems to fail, raising the following compilation error:

```
loc.map((x:Double) => x + 10.0)

 type mismatch;
   found   : Double => Double
   required: Any => ?
          loc.map( (x:Double) => x + 10.0 )
```

Can someone explain the rationale behind this and what is wrong with my syntax?  What is that required type signature trying to tell me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Product2.productIterator` returns `Iterator[Any]`, so the actual type of your list is `List[Any]`. This is why your `map` function is expecting a `Any => ?`.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Product2

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern matching (`case`)

```
loc map {case (x:Double) => x + 10.0}
```